# How is voltage on a clock is useful?

Tags: voltage, clock

I have this question. We provide clock and voltage in a circuit. The clock has some peak to peak value such as 0 to 1.8 volts, for instance. What is this meaning of this voltage? Does this mean a clock is nothing but a pulsating voltage?

Comment: You mean a specific value, like 1.8V, or do you mean voltage at all?

Comment: I mean in specifications it is given as 1.8v, 3.072MHz clock. Here 1.8 volt means that clock signal have a value between 0 to 1.8 v. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this question is too vague and broad to be on topic here.  Please refer to the [Help Center](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help) to better understand what's on topic here and generally how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 3):

A clock is just a pulsating voltage in the same way a metronome is just a pulsating sound. The voltage is there to differentiate not-voltage like the sound to differentiate from not-sound.

As for the specific value, it's because the clock is most likely being used in a digital circuit. The 1 or "on" for that digital circuit is any voltage over a certain threshold and the 0 or "off" is any value below a certain threshold. The voltage of the clock high value should be chosen based on the circuit you're attaching the clock to or will be based on the circuit the clock is coming from.

Read more about digital clocks [here](http://www.designcabana.com/knowledge/electrical/electronics/digital/clock/).

Edit:
Based on the analog clock vs digital clock comment, this would be an example of interpreting a sine wave as a digital clock:

[image]

A sine wave might be seen as a digital clock tick any time the voltage crosses from negative to positive. The "tick" point can be arbitrary as long as it's consistent.

Comment: So there is analog clock, and digital clock. Analog is literally vibrations as quartz, whereas digital clock contain pulses of detectable voltage by the circuit. Is it?

Comment: @mrigendra Digital is just an abstraction of analog in electronics. You can interpret an analog clock as digital. For instance, count a tick whenever the voltage rises above a particular threshold. I'll add a picture.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The given link is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

A clock signal is a signal that oscillates between low and high state continuously, usually at 50% duty cycle. It is used to coordinate digital circuits.

A faster clock will generally require more voltage.  In general, CMOS gates only use current when they switch states.  So the faster the clock speed is, the more often gates are switching, thus more current is switched, and more power is consumed.

So in the end, you can either trigger the digital circuit from low to high (rising edge) or high to low (falling edge).  Faster the circuit, more power will be required to operate the clock due to CMOS gates switching and consuming current.